# C++ sort coordinates stored as object in vector

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, object, stdvector

In the next code I can input a number ***n*** then I can input ***n*** number of ***(x,y)*** coordinates.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n = 0;
char cr;
class punto{
private:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    punto();
    ~punto(){}
    void setx(int xn){ x = xn;}
    void sety(int yn) { y = yn; }
    void printcoord();
};
punto::punto()
{
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
void punto:: printcoord()
{
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}
int main()
{
    vector<punto> list;
    int x;
        int y;
        punto *p1;
    cin >> n >> cr;
    for(int contador=0; contador<n; contador++){
        if(contador<n){
                cin >> x;
                cin >> y;
                p1=new punto;
                p1->setx(x);
                p1->sety(y);
                list.push_back(*p1);
                cin.get();
            }
        }
    vector<punto>::iterator it;
    if(cr=='x'){
     for ( it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it ) {
            it->printcoord();
     }
    }
    if(cr=='y'){
     for ( it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it ) {
            it->printcoord();
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That means that if we input this:

```
5 x
1 2
3 4
6 1
2 2
1 1
```

We get this output.

```
1 2
3 4
6 1
2 2
1 1
```

Problem is I don't know how to sort coordinates with respect to ***x*** or ***y***.

Coordinates are stored as objects within a vector.

If I try to use ***sort*** it says that ***x*** and ***y*** are non-class type ***int***.

Output should be:

```
1 1                    1 1
1 2                    6 1 
2 2     for x          1 2          for y    
3 4                    2 2 
6 1                    3 4
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Output should be:
>
> ```
> 1 1                    1 1
> 1 2                    6 1 
> 2 2     for x          1 2          for y    
> 3 4                    2 2 
> 6 1                    3 4
> ```

So basically you wanna sort objects w.r.t either **y** or **x**. 
One simple way of doing it is defining `operator<` for your class `punto`

```
bool operator<(const punto& obj)
{
   return this->y < obj.y;   // this will help you to sort w.r.t Y
}
```

Now you can simply use `std::sort()`, how you normally use it.

```
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end());
```

---

In order to sort w.r.t **x**s, you can write a `lambda` function which will use getters(which you need to define in the class `punto`) of your class.

```
   // define getters to access the private memebers
   const int& getX()const { return x; }
   const int& getY()const { return y; }
```

Then you can do as follows:

```
   // to sort w.r.t Xs: std::sort() with lambda
   std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(),[](const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs)->bool
                                       {  return lhs.getX() < rhs.getX(); });
```

[SEE OUTPUT HERE](https://www.ideone.com/axPtkQ)

---

However, I didn't understand why you have created `punto *p1;` and every time you have `push_back` the content to the vector.

**One dangerous thing** to note that, whatever you have created using `new` keyword, hasn't been deleted after, which is a serious memory leak issue in your problem.

You could have also use simply `punto p1;`  or use [Smart Pointers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory), if you really wanna play with dynamic memory.

Comment: @Erick.1993: welcome . Here is another simpler way, which nobody has mentioned in the answers: https://www.ideone.com/GAeXpf

Comment: @Erick.1993: if you are interested in Smart Pointers, here is a possible way of your program:  https://www.ideone.com/37aqaC

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lambda-functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) (since C++11) to make your code more laconic:

```
sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [x](const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs) {
    if (x == 'x')
        return lhs.x < rhs.x;
    else
        return lhs.y < rhs.y;
});
```

`[x]` means, that variable `x` is visible inside lambda function (see [lambda-capture](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) to sort a `std::vector`. To sort a class  it needs to have a `operator<` defined or you need to supply a custom comparator.

In your case the variables `x` and `y` are also private, to work around that we can make friend functions that can compare the `x` and `y` and pass them in as comparators to `std::sort`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int n = 0;
char cr;
class punto{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
public:
    punto();
    ~punto(){}
    void setx(int xn){ x = xn;}
    void sety(int yn) { y = yn; }
    void printcoord();

    friend bool compare_x(const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs);
    friend bool compare_y(const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs);
};
punto::punto()
{
    x=0;
    y=0;
}
void punto:: printcoord()
{
    cout << x << " " << y << endl;
}

bool compare_x(const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs) {
    if (lhs.x == rhs.x)
        return lhs.y < rhs.y;

    return lhs.x < rhs.x;
}

bool compare_y(const punto& lhs, const punto& rhs) {
    if (lhs.y == rhs.y)
        return lhs.x < rhs.x;

    return lhs.y < rhs.y;
}
int main()
{
    vector<punto> list;
    int x;
        int y;
        punto *p1;
    cin >> n >> cr;
    for(int contador=0; contador<n; contador++){
        if(contador<n){
                cin >> x;
                cin >> y;
                p1=new punto;
                p1->setx(x);
                p1->sety(y);
                list.push_back(*p1);
                cin.get();
            }
        }
    vector<punto>::iterator it;
    if(cr=='x'){
     std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), compare_x);
     for ( it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it ) {
            it->printcoord();
     }
    }
    if(cr=='y'){
     std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), compare_y);
     for ( it = list.begin(); it != list.end(); ++it ) {
            it->printcoord();
     }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @super I suggest you don't repeat the bad coding of the OP, such as `p1=new punto;`

Answer (score 0):

You could add `getters` for `x` & `y` to your `punto` class and then you can pass a custom comparator to `std::sort`:

```
// in class punto
// add getters to punto
int getX() {
    return x;
}
int getY() {
    return y;
}

// in main
std::sort(list.begin(), list.end(), [](punto& a, punto& b) {
    // sort by x
    return a.getX() > b.getX();
    // sort by y
    return a.getY() > b.getY();   
});
```